# CSS: Visual Hint That Text Overflows

Tags: html, text, overflow, css

I'm looking for a way to mark when text overflows it's container. The code goes like in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/3YUZY/1/). Basically, it's a `<span>` with a set size. I want some kind of marker to show me when the text overflows.

I tried `text-overflow:ellipsis;`, which sounded perfect, except that it only works if the parent is the one whose size is restricted (right?).

**Does anyone have any pure-CSS** (JS and editing the HTML is out of the question here) **ideas for how to alert me to when the text is being clipped?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add the `white-space: nowrap;` style to the container along with the `text-overflow:ellipsis;`.
See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3YUZY/4/)

**Edit** [Here's](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html) some more info on it.